# MongoDB: installed MongoDB on windows as a service to use on WAMP doesnt use the conf file?

Tags: windows, mongodb, configuration, config

I have installed MongoDB: mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.5 as a service so I can use it with WAMP.

I am following this: http://blog.tejaspmehta.com/setup-mongodb-with-wamp/

Funny thing is: mongod is starting up looking for its default data position which is /data/db. Of which I dont have bc I installed it as a service. But I have specified in my install as a service to use the configuration file

My configuration file is this so far:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "C:/wamp64/bin/mongodb/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.5/logs/mongodb.log"
  logAppend: true
  timeStampFormat: iso8601-local

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

storage:
  dbPath: "C:/wamp64/bin/mongodb/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.5/data/db"
  directoryPerDB: true
```

When I manually created the data/db/ directory, the mongod runs fine.

When I delete the data/db/ directory the mongod shutsdown from the following error:

```
...
options: {}
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
...
```

seems like the config file isnt working.

Comment: The config file is not being used.  The `options: {}` in the log is showing you all of the config file and command line options that were applied.

Comment: @Joe ow am I supposed to initialize the config file with mongod? Is the config file supposed to be at a specific location or am I supposed to install it by telling the config file has a specific path?

Comment: It needs to be at the location you specified when you set up the mongod service in windows.

Comment: Check if service installed correctly and you can see `--config` parameter points to your configuration [shown here](https://ibb.co/f4X9vn9)

Comment: @Valijon looking at the MongoDB service properties mine has no quotations on it. I read that was a known bug. Is that the issue? But I can start and stop the service using `net start MongoDB`

Comment: reinstalled with quoted paths to config to have the same path to executable as shown above and still the issue is not resolved...